# Pull request contains commits from master

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I branched from master a week ago.

```
master -> my_branch_1
```

During this time I've made commits to `my_branch_1` and also rebased on `origin/master` several times to keep up.

State of the branches ATM (conceptualised)

```
commit0
master -> my_branch_1

master:
   commit1
   commit3
   commit10

my_branch_1 (commits from master are marked with *)
   commit1*
   commit2
   commit3*
   commit4...commit9
   commit10
```

The problem appear when I attempt to open a PR back into `master`. PR log show all commits `1...10`, while I expect only commits `2, 4...9` would appear.

1. What have I done wrong?
2. How should I fix this?

**-- EDIT --**

Clarification on the `origin` discussion in comments. The intention was to receive commits that happened on master into my branch.

This was the desired outcome as I wanted to stay as close to "`master`" as possible to keep in sync with the rest of the code base.

What I don't want is to have these commits that are already in `master` appear in my PR that I'm doing into `master`

**-- EDIT 2 --**

This issue is with a private repo, hosted on GitHub. Not a forked repo.

Comment: Is `origin` your fork, or the repo you forked from?

Comment: The repo (github) I forked from.

Comment: Sounds like your pulled in those commits when you rebased. I would check what your `origin` is.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I believe I did, please see clarification. Have I done the process itself wrong?

Comment: You're doing a PR into your repo or the forked repo? If you are doing a PR into your repo, you should see that changes because the files might not exist. If you are doing a PR into the forked repo that means you changed something or something is different.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I'm working on a private repo, not a forked repo. The files and commits appear both in our `master` branch commit log and in my PR commits history.

Comment: Caleb, MaxBaldwin: I believe the terminology of forked was the confusion. I've **branched** from master, not forked into a different repo. My applogies.

Comment: @MaximVeksler That doesn't really matter as long as you're talking about two different branches.

Comment: @Caleb yes, these are different branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What have I done wrong?

It sounds like you pulled from `origin/master` rather than rebasing, at least to get `commit3`.

> How should I fix this?

First, create a backup branch from your branch in case you screw things up. You can do that just by making a new branch from your current one. If you're in the branch you're working on, for example, you can:

```
git checkout -b my_branch_1_backup
```

to create a new branch, and then just `checkout` to get back to your working branch:

```
git checkout my_branch_1
```

Second, rebase again. I'd start by doing an interactive rebase and just removing the commits you don't want. Use the `-i` flag to rebase interactively, like:

```
git rebase -I commit1
```

This will give you a list of commits going back to `commit1` that you can edit, like:

```
pick commit2
pick commit3
pick commit4
```

and so on. If you don't want `commit3` (because it's already in `master`), change `pick commit3` to `drop commit3`. There will be a list of other options in a comment in your editor. Once you've fixed up your list of commits, save and exit the editor, and do a:

```
git log
```

You should see that the log reflects your changes.

Finally, you can rebase to `origin/master`, which will make git get any new commits in `master` and then add your commits on top of the ones from `master`:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Check the log again and you should see the commits from `master` in your log, but before the commits you added in your branch.

At that point, your pull request should include only the commits you added in your branch.

Comment: Would it be please possible to provide command line step by step for this?

Comment: @MaximVeksler Added examples. I was typing from memory, so please be cautious. I cannot emphasize enough the importance of the first step, making a backup of your branch before you use the very powerful `rebase` command to alter your branch's history.

Comment: that you very much for the technique, I think I still don't understand the theoreory enough. WHY did it happen in the first place? Could you please hypnotise ? And WHY your solution fixes it? (It does, thank you!). I mean to ask what have I done differently from what you are doing because on the face of it it seems our flows are the same (conceptually) only I did git rebase origin/master several times during the development and you only did it once as the final stage.

Comment: If you just `pull` from one branch to another, any new commits in that branch (that is, ones you don't already have) get added to your branch on top of the commits that are already there. The `rebase` command lets you rewrite your branch's history (which makes it powerful, and therefore a bit dangerous). You can rebase from another branch, which as its name suggests changes the "base" of your branch to that other branch -- it adds your commits "on top" of the commits in that branch.

Comment: so the reason the Github decided to display my commits (in the branch) along with the master commits that I've pulled from master is because my commits  were not stacked at the very top? Meaning that it won't "check and pick" only the commits that are coming into master that are not already there but instead will take the first commit that is not in master and ANYTHING above in the timeline?

Comment: If it merged commits in your branch prior to the HEAD commit of the branch you're merging into, then you'd be rewriting the history of that branch (`master` in this case). Also, it's important to maintain the order of commits -- reordering commits can change the result.

Comment: @Caleb `git pull origin master` should take the commits and apply them to your local branch. However they shouldn't be part of the diff, because they were already in master. Why would you say that `git pull orign main` is wrong in this case?